# how can I do an implicit conversion from a lambda expression to a custom class?

Tags: c#, lambda, implicit-conversion

I have created a class for lazy argument passing:

```
public struct LazyValue<T>
{
    private Func<T> _fetchFunction;
    private bool _fetched;
    private T _cachedValue;

    public LazyValue(Func<T> fetchFunction)
    {
        _fetchFunction = fetchFunction;
        _fetched = false;
        _cachedValue = default(T);
    }

    public LazyValue(T fixedValue)
    {
        _fetchFunction = null;
        _fetched = true;
        _cachedValue = fixedValue;
    }

    public static implicit operator LazyValue<T>(Func<T> fetchFunction)
    {
        return new LazyValue<T>(fetchFunction);
    }

    public static implicit operator LazyValue<T>(T fixedValue)
    {
        return new LazyValue<T>(fixedValue);
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (_fetched) { return _cachedValue; }

            T value = default(T);

            if (_fetchFunction != null)
            {
                value = _fetchFunction();
            }

            _cachedValue = value;
            _fetched = true;

            return value;
        }
    }

    // other members omitted here
}
```

Now I also have a method accepting this type as a parameter:

```
public ReturnType SomeMethod(SomeType param1, LazyValue<TimeSpan> param2)
```

I can call the method with a fixed value (a TimeSpan instance) without any problems.
But it seems it is not possible to call the method with a lambda expression for param2. The compiler complains with:

```
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'LazyValue<System.TimeSpan>' because it
is not a delegate type
```

I think this is because the compiler cannot do a two-step implicit conversion: first lambda to `Func<TimeSpan>` and then the conversion to `LazyValue<TimeSpan>`.

I know I can get the thing to compile by adding an explicit conversion, like this:

```
SomeMethod(arg1, new Func<TimeSpan>(() => my_expression_here))
```

...but that would be kind of painful to do. I would like to avoid the syntactic overhead of an explicit conversion. I would really prefer to write:

```
SomeMethod(arg1, () => my_expression_here)
```

I could also change the type of param2 to `Func<TimeSpan>` and do the conversion to `LazyValue` in the method itself, but that seems less elegant to me.

Is there a way to get the implicit conversion to `LazyValue<T>` to work for lambdas? I would really like to have this just work:

```
TimeSpan oneHour = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
SomeMethod(arg1, oneHour);
SomeMethod(arg1, () => Settings.Instance.GetTimeSpan("mysetting"));
```

Comment: You should look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What about having `SomeMethod` expect a `Func<LazyValue<TimeSpan>>` and using a method group/lambda to call it e.g. `SomeMethod(arg1, my_expression_here)` or `SomeMethod(arg1, () => my_expression_here)`, or you could just provide an overload. I'm sure there are some frameworks that just use overloads for this

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the compiler doesn't chain implicit conversions, and that's you have to explicitly instantiate a `new Func<TimeSpan>(() => my_expression_here)`

From [Implicit and Explicit Conversion Operators in C#](http://simpleprogrammer.com/2013/01/20/implicit-and-explicit-conversion-operators-in-c/):

> Also the conversions can’t chain automatically.  If you have a conversion to type a Dog to a Cat and a Cat to a Mouse, you can’t assign a Dog directly to a Mouse.

Comment: The compiler doesn't chain _user-defined_ implicit conversions, but will chain one standard implicit conversion from src and one standard implicit conversion to destination with a user-defined conversion between. I found why this doesn't work, however - only standard implicit conversions are chained with a user-defined conversion and the conversion of a lambda expression (or anonymous method) to a delegate is not one of them (specification 6.3.1).